# How determine the bandwidth of a gaussian kernel such that k nearest points represent a certain % of sum weight

Tags: normal-distribution, kernel-smoothing

I have a dataset to which I am applying a gaussian kernel. I want to determine the bandwidth (sd) of the kernel such that, on average, the *k* nearest points will represent a specified proportion of the resulting weights. For example, say I have a hundred observations with m=0.5 and sd=0.25, how do I determine the bw of a gaussian kernel such that, for any given point, on average the 10 nearest points will represent 95% of the sum of all weights?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure, but a 'rough' approximation would be to have 10 observations on average lying within 2 standard deviations. The thing is the area that contains the 10-nearest-neighbours is actually adaptive to the local density. If you use a constant bandwidth, the window size of the gaussian kernel would be static, so in some cases might contain less or much more than 10 neighbours (especially at the boundaries). If your goal to select a constant bandwidth I would go the simple way:

- Select a range of bandwidths and find weights for each one
- For each query point and for each bandwidth, estimate the ratio of weights that you target and create a histogram
- Select the bandwidth that fits your goal

Comment: this is really helpful, thank you! my problem with the solution exactly as you've described it is that it would be very slow (for my actual problem, this will need to be run many times on large datasets, so speed will be relevant) but i think it's got me a long way in the right direction!

Comment: ...except that i've realised that having 10 observations within 2sd *won't* approximate 95% of weights, because this is happening in 2d, not 1d - so area under a 1d gaussian within 2sd of the mean is approx. 95%, but that is not true of the volume under a 2d gaussian within 2sd of the mean. is tht right?

Comment: Still my suggestion holds, you'll still have to try it for different bandwidths and estimate the percentage of weights for the 10 NNs. But sure, this is a slow approach.

Comment: @tzirtzi the fact that it's in 1D changes things (many more options available than high dimensional case); you should add this to the main question :)